# Maximizing an Delphi (VCL) application externally using windows API

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke, showwindow

I try to start another application that is written in Delphi in my C# application using this code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName="app.exe";
process.Start();
```

It happens that users minimize that another app. So, sometimes I want to bring that window from the minimized state to maximized state, and show on top of my C# application. When I try to maximize it, using Windows API calls:

```
 ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZED); -- SW_MAXIMIZED=3
```

It shows me a black screen instead of application:
[image: Effect of ShowWindow]

I guess it's due to how VCL applications works.
I have tried different approaches (SW_RESTORE, SW_SHOW), then tried to SetForeGroundWindow (also didn't help - it only works when window is not minimized).

What's more, after maximizing it with `ShowWindow`programatically, I can still maximize that external app window from the taskbar manually, and it works. Also when I minimize manually the window, a black window minimizes as well.

If I close that black window, the external Delphi application is being closed too.

After some time wasted today, I found out that sending alt+tab using `SendKeys` class worked.
However, that's a very naive, and I don't accept it as a solution, since user could have any other window opened before (not only an external application), so then that another window will be on top.

Any ideas how to deal with that, or what is actually happening?

I tried to dig in VCL documentation, but I couldn't find proper explanation about what is happening.

Comment: According to [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow): _SW_RESTORE - Activates and displays the window. If the window is minimized, maximized, or arranged, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when restoring a minimized window_

Comment: Output the window handle of your Delphi program and compare that with what `process.MainWindowHandle` of your C# program holds - both may differ and you may make false assumptions.

Comment: @AmigoJack gonna check it with dnSpy tommorow, but highly doubt it. SetWindowsForeground works fine when windows is not minimized. If i would have bad hook, it wouldnt work i guess. However, thank you for your comment.

Comment: No need to use external tools - set the application's title (thus the task button's text) to the window handle in both cases.

Comment: @AmigoJack you was right. I got a wrong handle, and under the comment of the first answer, there is more detailed info from mr Remy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits go to @RemyLebeau for finding a reason of the problem i described, which also led me to finding a correct solution (found proper window handle instead of what i was finding before). I just copied it from the comment section.

> The 1st window created by a Delphi VCL app is a hidden utility window,
> not the actual UI window the user sees on-screen. So
> process.MainWindowHandle is likely picking up the wrong window, which
> is why you end up maximizing a blank window. The Win32 API has no
> concept of a "main window", that is an entirely made-up concept in the
> .NET world, and it doesn't always translate well when dealing with
> external non .NET processes.

> ... In older Delphi versions, VCL `TForm` windows are owned by the
> hidden `TApplication` window by default. The hidden `TApplication`
> window is an unowned window. In newer versions, the old behavior can
> be re-enabled by setting `TApplication.MainFormOnTaskbar=False`

Remy, if you want to post an answer here i will delete mine, i just wanted to post an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Process.MainWindowHandle Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=net-8.0) documentation you should call `Process.Refresh` beforehand in order to guarantee that you will retrieve current value.

> The main window is the window opened by the process that currently has
> the focus (the TopLevel form). You must use the Refresh method to
> refresh the Process object to get the most up to date main window
> handle if it has changed. In general, because the window handle is
> cached, use Refresh beforehand to guarantee that you'll retrieve the
> current handle.

Comment: The 1st window created by a Delphi VCL app is a hidden utility window, not the actual UI window the user sees on-screen.  So `process.MainWindowHandle` is likely picking up the wrong window, which is why you end up maximizing a blank window. The Win32 API has no concept of a "main window", that is an entirely made-up concept in the .NET world, and it doesn't always translate well when dealing with external non .NET processes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau so how come that `SetForegoundWindow` works fine when external application is not minimized? Shouldnt it bring the other window too, instead of bringing the correct window on the top of my form ?
@SilverWarior Nothing changed. I get same handle, even after refreshing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, you got right. It's apparently a different window handle- i just checked it with Spy++.  So, yea, i just have to find a proper window handle. You can write it as answer, and im gonna accept that. However its still unclear to me why `SetForegoundWindow` actually worked...
Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If I understand C# documentation `process.MainWindowHandle` is not the same as [TApplication.MainFormHandle](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MainFormHandle) in Delphi but more like [TApplication.ActiveFormHandle](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ActiveFormHandle)

Comment: @silverwarrior i guess it doesnt matter, since the very first window that is started is that `hidden utility window`, because this is the window handler that we get in `MainWindowHandle` after starting a process. I already checked that with spy++, and the window handle of `hidden utility window` is equal to MainWindowHandle, even after calling .Refresh method on a process.

Comment: @SilverWarior no, in this case the `process.MainWindowHandle` is likely finding the hidden `TApplication.Handle` window, which is different then either the `TApplication.MainFormHandle` or `TApplication.ActiveFormHandle` window

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220124-00/?p=106192 "*According to the BCL heuristics, any **unowned** visible window is a candidate for being the “main” window.*" in older Delphi versions, VCL `TForm` windows are **owned** by the hidden `TApplication` window by default. The hidden `TApplication` window is an **unowned**  window. In newer versions, the old behavior can be re-enabled by setting `TApplication.MainFormOnTaskbar=False`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could you post your first comment as an answer? It would be nice for the future possible visitors of stackoverflow that could face the same problem.